# Security Token Service (STS) access in a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS Security Token Service (STS) can only be accessed from the Internet, correct me if I am wrong.

My customer would like to access DynamoDB from an EC2 instance in the same AWS account.

The EC2 instance is in a private subnet without internet access. Does it mean EC2 instance cannot leverage STS? Is there a workaround for this? We try to avoid using permanent access key and secret key to access resources in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only STS, you need internet access to use any AWS service. For STS, the endpoint **https://sts.amazonaws.com** should be accessible. There are endpoints for each AWS service. The only service that doesn't need internet access is the metadata server **http://169.254.169.254**

If your security policy permits, you can add an internet route to your subnet through a NAT. You can let the instance access only certain IP address by setting the outbound rule in the security group.

Comment: You can use S3 without internet access via VPC endpoints, and they plan to add other services to that eventually. This is the correct answer at this time regarding STS though.

Comment: @MarkB you are correct. S3 can be accessed through VPC endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Start from 2020 Dec onwards, you can use sts VPC endpoint in private subnet which doesn't have outbound internet access.

[image]